# How to see page that failed to load on condition? (Selenium. Python)

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

Here is my code. In `Try` I am checking if specific text appears on load, if so process further. If I understand correctly, my code explicitly waits 10 seconds at every load and then waits another 15 until condition is met?

The question is, how can I see the page content after it fails to load and throws exception? I want to know why this happens, what is on the page or what is missing. Right now I reload the same page without condition, but since it is reloaded, it is not the same page that threw the exception. Is there any way to see the original page from `try`?

P.S. The while loop is just to check how it goes on scale.

P.P.S. I also try to append failed url to the list I iterate through. I believe it is a bad practice. But what harm can it make and what would be the best solution?

```
 driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path=r'C:\Python3\selenium\webdriver\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows\bin\phantomjs.exe',service_log_path=os.path.devnull)

while count < 20:
    for line in q:


        driver.get(line)
        try:
            WebDriverWait(driver, 40).until(EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.ID, 'searchProgressText'), 'Search complete'))

            text=driver.find_element_by_class_name("sortbar").text.encode().decode('ascii','ignore')

            start = text.find('Cheapest')
            stop = text.find('Best')
            date = (line[line.find('SDP0')+5:line.find('&AD')].split('&'))
            date = date[0]+ ' - ' + date[3][5:]
            dest = (' - ').join(line[line.find('SO0')+4:line.find('&SDP0')].split('&SD0='))
            print()
            print('count=', count)
            print(line)
            print(date)
            print(dest)
            print(text[start:stop])
            count+=1

        except:
            print()
            print('******')
            print('******')
            print("Failure", fcount, line)
            fcount+=1
        text=driver.find_element_by_id("searchProgressText").text.encode().decode('ascii','ignore')

        print(text)

        print('******')
        print('******')
        print()




        time.sleep(2)
driver.close()
```

This particular line takes too long to load. From 1.5 second up to 7 seconds. with most cases taking abour 3 seconds.

```
driver.get(line)
```

Is this ok? How can i influence the load time?

Comment: please create new questions for followup questions rather than editing your original question to ask new things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> how can I see the page content after it 
>   fails to load and throws exception?

by "see the page content", I'll assume you either mean saving a screenshot or saving the page source, so I will show both.

but basically, you catch the exception and do something there.

consider the following example.  It will wait up to 15 seconds for the expected condition to be met.  So it either returns an instance of `WebElement`, or else it throws a `TimeoutException`.  You can catch the exception and do whatever you like before continuing.  This example will print the exception detail, print the current page source, and save a screenshot.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get(some_url) 
try:
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)
    condition = EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'someid'))
    element = wait.until(condition)
except TimeoutException as e:
    print(e)
    print(driver.page_source)
    driver.save_screenshot('screen.png')
```

I gave a simplified example because your code contains *many* other problems.  It's best to start with the basics.

Comment: Hi. Yes, I want to see source code of that page, exactly as you have shown. Thank you.  What other issues are there in the code?

Comment: I see that     'text=driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME,("body")).text.encode().decode('ascii','ignore')' was highly inefficient. it took 4 to 11 seconds to process this part itself. After switching to 'text=driver.find_element_by_class_name("sortbar").text.encode().decode('ascii','ignore')' it now takes 0.1 sec to process.

Answer (score 1):

> If I understand correctly, my code explicitly waits 10 seconds at every load and then waits another 15 until condition is met?

That is not quite correct. Implicit is set on `driver` and applies for the life of that `driver` instance. It doesn't actually do anything at the time you set it. You can read [the docs](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#implicit-waits) to understand more but it basically just waits up to 10s each time you attempt to find an element and it's not immediately available.

You are using both implicit and explicit waits which you should not do per [the docs](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-and-implicit-waits).

> WARNING: Do not mix implicit and explicit waits. Doing so can cause unpredictable wait times.

You should remove the implicit wait and just use explicit waits (`WebDriverWait`), as needed.

To see the page content after it fails to load, the code in `except` is what is run when the expected element is not found. You would need to put your code to find what is or is not on the page there. You didn't state any specifics on what you wanted so you could take a screenshot, dump the HTML inside of a certain element to a log, etc. It just depends on what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for editing my question. It looked like a mess. (